# get data from html page using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have some HTML - pretty nasty, but not mine and so I don't have control over it. I need to extract some data from the form, the First name value (ABDIGANI) and the Surname value (AHMED). What is the best way to do this with javascript?

```
<div class="voffset3"></div>
    <div class="container well panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <span class="ax_paragraph">
                        First name
                    </span>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="ax_h5">
                            ABDIGANI
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <span class="ax_paragraph">
                        Surname
                    </span>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="ax_h5">
                            AHMED
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i should have also mentioned, that the class ax_h5 is not consistent the class changes depending on the page data retrieved, so it cannot be targeted on this class

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could consider HTML in most cases well structured. Try this the following snippet.

Edit: did a change due to the first comment.

Edit: if you have more than one rows, you should use

```
document.querySelectorAll('.container > .panel-body > .row');
```

and fetch the pairs for each found element as below.

```
const markers = ['First name', 'Surname'];
const mRx = [new RegExp(markers[0]), new RegExp(markers[1])];

function findMarker(element) {
    for(let i = 0; i < mRx.length; i++) {
        if(element.innerHTML.match(mRx[i])) {
            return markers[i];
        }
    }
    return null;
}

function findValue(el) {
    return el.parentElement.querySelector('.form-group > div').innerHTML.trim();
}

const pairs = [... document.querySelectorAll('.ax_paragraph')]
    .map(el => {
        return {el: el, mk: findMarker(el)};
    })
    .filter(n => n.mk !== null)
    .map(o => {
        return {key: o.mk, value: findValue(o.el)};
    });
console.log(pairs);
```

Comment: It works, but a bit overkill. Don't you think? Also .ax_h5 can not be used as Op mentioned in comment.

Comment: Overkill as for now, agreed. But consider there are many rows, and there already is a div with class "row". Then we have to to assign first names to surnames precisely even if there are some nodes missing.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var x = document.querySelectorAll(".panel-body > div >.col-md-3 > div > div");

x.forEach(myFunction);

function myFunction(item, index) {
  //console.log(item.innerHTML.trim());
  
  if (index===0){
  console.log("First name : "+item.innerHTML.trim());
  }
  if (index===1){
  console.log("Surname : "+item.innerHTML.trim());
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="voffset3"></div>
    <div class="container well panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <span class="ax_paragraph">
                        First name
                    </span>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="ax_h5">
                            ABDIGANI
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <span class="ax_paragraph">
                        Surname
                    </span>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="ax_h5">
                            AHMED
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this

```
const firstName = document.querySelector('.row .form-group div').textContent.trim();

const surname = document.querySelector('.row > div:last-child .form-group div').textContent.trim();
```

**note**: Its better to change html according to functionality needs, like if you need firstname then you must keep an id attribute to div which is having first name, same goes to surname. then select those fields using id selector, because even if you change html page structure in future, functionality will not get effected.

Check below for reference on how the html should actually be(just to make sure you know it, but the solution you are seeking is above in first two lines)
eg:

```
<div class="voffset3"></div>
    <div class="container well panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <span class="ax_paragraph">
                        First name
                    </span>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="ax_h5" id="firstNameField">
                            ABDIGANI
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <span class="ax_paragraph">
                        Surname
                    </span>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="ax_h5" id="surnameField">
                            AHMED
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @ikiK only first two lines are actual solution, below code is more like how to write html + javascript. your edit is not defferentiating these two codes. please edit text also accordingly and redit

Comment: I am sorry, my mistake, and looks like a can not cancel the edit. It is waiting to be   approved by trusted community members. Can not revert it. (it is not yet approved)

Comment: Please do. As you are fairly new here I was thinking to show how to make snippet. I haven't understand content right. Sorry one more time. I was bit fast on trigger ;)

Answer (score -1):

If you can't edit the HTML, you can use the XPATH for Example.

Comment: Hi @BPP-DEV what's xpath? Looks like a legacy code based on content which I read now in w3schools, can this code be used now a days.

Answer (score -1):

document.querySelector('.form-group > div').textContent but without modifying the html there is no way to distinguish first name and surname.

Comment: This is not correct. For each builds a index of elements  and if HTML markup is always the same as OP's example you can target items by index.